# Finding a basis for the range and null space of some $T:M_{2 \times 2}(R) \to M_{2 \times 2}(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$ and $T:M_{2 \times 2}(Q) \to M_{2 \times 2}(Q)$ be a linear transformation (where $Q$ is the field of rational numbers) given by $X \mapsto AX$. How would one find the basis of the null space of $T$ and the range of $T$? I'm sorry if the $A$ is badly chosen, this is just a proxy for a homework question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible, $T$ is invertible ($T^{-1}(X)=A^{-1}X$). Therefore, $\ker T=\{0\}$, a basis of which is $\emptyset$ (actually, it's the only basis). And the range of $T$ is $M^{2\times2}(\mathbb Q)$. So, you can use the standard basis of this space:$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

Comment: I see, so it would NOT be a simple matter if we had some arbitrary, non-invertible $A$?

Comment: No, not at all.